# Is there any other way to resize the stroke vector without Expanding it in Ai?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes, icon

I am creating some icons in Ai and want to resize the designed shapes.
But the problem is
I have stroke shapes, and when I am resizing, it changes its stroke size.

The way I knows is

1. Expand the shapes, by going
   `Object` > `Path` > `Outline Stroke`
2. In the preference enable the **Scale strokes and effect** setting
   [image: Reference Image]

But both cases have a drawback

In Case 1 : `Object` > `Path` > `Outline Stroke`
The *Lines get converted into fills.*

In Case 2: Line stroke sizes change.

I don't want my line strokes to be converted into the fill, so is there any other way to achieve it rather than creating a new one?

[image: Video]

Please see the image for your better understanding.
[image]

Comment: This doesn't make a great deal of sense to me. If you *allow* strokes to scale, then their size is reduced as you reduce the object - same basic behavior as if you outlined the strokes but they *remain live* strokes. Is that not what you want? In your sample animation, just allow strokes to scale.

Comment: @Scott I am assuming you did not understand my question. For your better understanding, I have added another image to the question. Maybe that will help.

Comment: Hi Sumit, that doesn't help. I know what the functions are and how they work.. what I don't seem to understand is what you *want*??? Or what you're expecting to happen which isn't happening. You aren't explaining your **problem**. You seem to be merely describing *how features work*. If you *want* the stroke size to remain the same, *untick* scale strokes.. if you *want* the stroke size to change then *tick* scale strokes. Where is the issue??

Comment: It would kind of seem that you are expecting strokes to *not* scale, but also to operate as if they were fills, which *would* scale. So the question appears to ask for two things which are *direct opposites* and not possible. i.e. want them to scale, but not change size.  This is what I am not grasping. By sheer definition, scaling **is** changing size in all instances, 100% of the time, regardless of whether they are strokes or fills.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- scale the strokes with scale (the option needs to be *checked*) or
- you can make them not scale with scale (the option is unchecked).

Those are the basic options. And yes the effects you get are consistent with your options. Scale strokes behaves as if the object was expanded. There are in some cases where live round corners glitches, just nudge points back and forth this should fix that issue.

[image]

**Image 1**: The basic options. First one scales strokes second one does not (so they stay the same).

You can also scale just strokes if you wish in the scale tool or scale menu option buy unchecking all options except scale strokes and effects. So in essence all the possible elementary options that you could possibly need are covered. (you can also scale nonuniform if you wish, by transforming then scaling stroke and untransforming)